# LWP::Simple - how to implement a loop into it [with live demo]

Tags: perl, parsing, loops, cvs, lwp

good evening dear community!

i want to process multiple webpages, kind of like a web spider/crawler might. I have some bits - but now i need to have some improved spider-logic. See the target-url http://192.68.214.70/km/asps/schulsuche.asp?q=e&a=50

This page has got more than 6000 results! Well how do i get all the results?
I use the module LWP::simple and i need to have some improved arguments that i can use in order to get all the 6150 records

**Attempt:** Here are the first 5 page URLs:

```
http://192.68.214.70/km/asps/schulsuche.asp?q=e&a=50&s=0 
http://192.68.214.70/km/asps/schulsuche.asp?q=e&a=50&s=50 
http://192.68.214.70/km/asps/schulsuche.asp?q=e&a=50&s=100 
http://192.68.214.70/km/asps/schulsuche.asp?q=e&a=50&s=150 
http://192.68.214.70/km/asps/schulsuche.asp?q=e&a=50&s=200
```

We can see that the "s" attribute in the URL starts at 0 for page 1, then increases by 50 
for each page there after. We can use this information to create a loop:

```
my $i_first = "0"; 
my $i_last = "6100"; 
my $i_interval = "50"; 

for (my $i = $i_first; $i <= $i_last; $i += $i_interval) { 
     my $pageurl = "http://192.68.214.70/km/asps/schulsuche.asp?q=e&a=50&s=$i"; 
     #process pageurl 
}
```

tadmc (a very very supportive user) has created a great script that puts out a cvs-formated results. i have build in this loop in the code:  (Note - i guess that there has gone wrong something! See the musings below... with the code-snippets and the error-messages:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use LWP::Simple;
use HTML::TableExtract;
use Text::CSV;

my $i_first = "0"; 
my $i_last = "6100"; 
my $i_interval = "50"; 

for (my $i = $i_first; $i <= $i_last; $i += $i_interval) { 
     my $pageurl = "http://192.68.214.70/km/asps/schulsuche.asp?q=e&a=50&s=$i"; 
     #process pageurl 
}

my $html= get 'http://192.68.214.70/km/asps/schulsuche.asp?q=n&a=50';
$html =~ tr/r//d;     # strip the carriage returns
$html =~ s/&nbsp;/ /g; # expand the spaces

my $te = new HTML::TableExtract();
$te->parse($html);

my @cols = qw(
    rownum
    number
    name
    phone
    type
    website
);

my @fields = qw(
    rownum
    number
    name
    street
    postal
    town
    phone
    fax
    type
    website
);

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ binary => 1 });

foreach my $ts ($te->table_states) {
    foreach my $row ($ts->rows) {

trim leading/trailing whitespace from base fields
        s/^s+//, s/\s+$// for @$row;

load the fields into the hash using a "hash slice"
        my %h;
        @h{@cols} = @$row;

derive some fields from base fields, again using a hash slice
        @h{qw/name street postal town/} = split /n+/, $h{name};
        @h{qw/phone fax/} = split /n+/, $h{phone};

trim leading/trailing whitespace from derived fields
        s/^s+//, s/\s+$// for @h{qw/name street postal town/};

        $csv->combine(@h{@fields});
        print $csv->string, "\n";
    }
}
```

There have been some issues - i have made a mistake i guess that the error is here:

```
for (my $i = $i_first; $i <= $i_last; $i += $i_interval) { 
 my $pageurl = "http://192.68.214.70/km/asps/schulsuche.asp?q=e&a=50&s=$i"; 
      #process pageurl 
    }

my $html= get 'http://192.68.214.70/km/asps/schulsuche.asp?q=n&a=50';
$html =~ tr/r//d;     # strip the carriage returns
$html =~ s/&nbsp;/ /g; # expand the spaces
```

i have written down some kind of double - code. I need to leave out one part ... this one here

```
my $html= get 'http://192.68.214.70/km/asps/schulsuche.asp?q=n&a=50';
$html =~ tr/r//d;     # strip the carriage returns
$html =~ s/&nbsp;/ /g; # expand the spaces
```

see the results in  the command line:

```
martin@suse-linux:~> cd perl
martin@suse-linux:~/perl> perl bavaria_all_.pl
Possible unintended interpolation of %h in string at bavaria_all_.pl line 52.
Possible unintended interpolation of %h in string at bavaria_all_.pl line 52.
Global symbol "%h" requires explicit package name at bavaria_all_.pl line 52.
Global symbol "%h" requires explicit package name at bavaria_all_.pl line 52.
syntax error at bavaria_all_.pl line 59, near "/,"
Global symbol "%h" requires explicit package name at bavaria_all_.pl line 59.
Global symbol "%h" requires explicit package name at bavaria_all_.pl line 60.
Global symbol "%h" requires explicit package name at bavaria_all_.pl line 60.
Substitution replacement not terminated at bavaria_all_.pl line 63.
martin@suse-linux:~/perl>
```

what do you think!?
look forward to hear from you

btw - see the code, **created by tadmc**, without any improved spider-logic....This runs very very nciely - without any issue: it spits out a nice formatted cvs-output!!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use LWP::Simple;
use HTML::TableExtract;
use Text::CSV;

my $html= get 'http://192.68.214.70/km/asps/schulsuche.asp?q=n&a=50';
$html =~ tr/r//d;     # strip the carriage returns
$html =~ s/&nbsp;/ /g; # expand the spaces

my $te = new HTML::TableExtract();
$te->parse($html);

my @cols = qw(
    rownum
    number
    name
    phone
    type
    website
);

my @fields = qw(
    rownum
    number
    name
    street
    postal
    town
    phone
    fax
    type
    website
);

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ binary => 1 });

foreach my $ts ($te->table_states) {
    foreach my $row ($ts->rows) {

trim leading/trailing whitespace from base fields
        s/^s+//, s/\s+$// for @$row;

load the fields into the hash using a "hash slice"
        my %h;
        @h{@cols} = @$row;

derive some fields from base fields, again using a hash slice
        @h{qw/name street postal town/} = split /n+/, $h{name};
        @h{qw/phone fax/} = split /n+/, $h{phone};

trim leading/trailing whitespace from derived fields
        s/^s+//, s/\s+$// for @h{qw/name street postal town/};

        $csv->combine(@h{@fields});
        print $csv->string, "\n";
    }
}
```

Note: this above mentioned code runs nicely - it spits out csv-formated output.

Comment: Do you expect us to count lines to figure out which one is line 52? I am too busy for that...

Comment: hello dear tadmc - no i do not! Here line 52
        s/^s+//, s/\s+$// for @$row;

Comment: it is missing a backslash. The errors are because you have removed the comment markers (#), so the comments are being interpreted as Perl code...

Comment: hello tadmc - many thanks - i will rework the code and try it again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A different approach to achieve paging is to extract all URLs from the page and detect the pager URLs.

```
... 
for (@urls) { 
    if (is_pager_url($_) and not exists $seen{$_}) {
         push @pager_url, $_; 
         $seen{$_}++; 
    }
}
... 

sub is_pager_url { 
    my ($url) = @_; 
    return 1 if $url =~ m{schulsuche.asp\?q=e\&a=\d+\&s=\d+};
}
```

This way you don't have to deal with incrementing counters or establishing the total number of pages.  It will also work for different values of a and s.  By keeping a %seen hash, you can cheaply avoid differentiating between prev and next pages.

Comment: hello Vipul Ved Prakash - this looks very very impressive. later today I will try this out! many thanks for the  posting!

Comment: i try to figure out how to apply this approach.... It looks intersting and fascinating!

Answer (score 1):

Excellent! I was waiting for you to figure out how to get the multiple pages on your own!

1) put my code *inside* of the page-getting loop (move the "}" way down to the end).

2) $html = get $pageurl; # change this to use your new URL

3) put my backslash back where I had it: tr/\r//d;

Comment: hello dear tadmc! Great to hear  from you!! I am very glad! - as you see i have some troubles. I guess that i have to comment out some lines. Is it that what you want from me. I now try to read your comments 1.to 3 again and try to understand these in thorough detail?...